# Twitter Bootstrap - Passing a unique ID to a Modal

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched a lot and am still having some trouble passing a Unique Id to a Value and then using that ID for a PHP MySQL Query to get the book info.

I currently am passing the unique ID to the Modal and Displaying it through an input type text. I am just having a hard time figuring out how to put the id into a php Variable

Here is my HTMl/PHP code

```
                    echo '<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="' . $book_id .'" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">View Info</a>';?>

        <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal hide" id="addBookDialog">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                        <h3>Book Info</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>some content</p>
                        <?php 
                        echo $test = '<input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId"/>';

                            $book_info = get_book_info($book_id);

                            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($book_info))
                            {
                                $email = $row['email'];
                                echo "<p><strong>Title: </strong>" . $row1['title'] . "</p>";
                                echo "<p><strong>Author: </strong>" . $row1['author'] . "</p>";
                                echo "<p><strong>Edition: </strong>" . $row1['edition'] . "</p>";
                                echo "<p><strong>ISBN: </strong>" . $row1['isbn'] . "</p>";
                                echo "<p><strong>Price: </strong>" . $row1['price'] . "</p>";
                                echo "<p><strong>Seller's Name: </strong>" . $row1['name'] . "</p>";
                                echo "<p><strong>Seller's E-mail: </strong><a href='mailto:$email'>$email</a></p>";
                            }?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

here is my jquery

```
        $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
         var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
         $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
    });
```

Comment: I donot understand your question. Could you please tell us what your concrete problem is and what you already have tried?

Comment: My problem is passing a php variable to a modal and then uae a query to display information of a book that has that id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this by javascript/coffee script.

```
($ "a[data-toggle=modal]").click ->
target = ($ @).attr('data-target')
url = ($ @).attr('href')
($ target).load(url)
```

URL = unique ID

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the value:

```
data-id="<?php $book_id ?>"
```

Use this instead:

```
data-id="<?php echo $book_id; ?>"
```

Comment: I am already echoing it out. I edited my question to reflect on what i have.

Comment: It did help i had to use ajax